# Bootstrap accordion won't collapse previously shown div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have the following code snippet which is doing accordion. It collapses and hides once clicked. However, when one is currently collapsed and another one will be clicked, the first collapsed div won't hide. Instead, it will collapse the next one as well, resulting to two collapsed divs.

```
<script src="../../S/Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="../../S/Content/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="../../S/Content/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


<link href="../../S/Content/stylesheets/_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../S/Content/stylesheets/ui-custom-style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../S/Content/stylesheets/_ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

        <div class="col-sm-8 badges-area">
            <div class="row badge-items" id="accordion">
                <div class="col-sm-4 badge-item" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#badge-info-body">
                     <img src="../img/badge-sample.png"/>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4 badge-item" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#try">
                     <img src="../img/badge-sample.png"/>
                </div>

                <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="col-sm-11 badge-info arrow arrow-left panel-collapse collapse" id="badge-info-body" role="tabpanel" >
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                       <img src="../img/badge-sample.png"/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">                           
                       <p> This is for the first.
                        </p>  
                   </div>                    


               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-11 badge-info arrow arrow-middle panel-collapse collapse" id="try" role="tabpanel" >
                   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                       <img src="../img/badge-sample.png"/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
                       <p> This is for the second.
                        </p>    
                   </div>                       
               </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Where could I possibly went wrong? Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23951/ When I click the First Accordion, it will collapse, which is okay. When I click the Second Accordion, the previous one didn't close but it collapsed another one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: create a fiddle , so we can help

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ Thanks @Mir

Comment: You have some wrong content in the jsfiddle.

Comment: My bad. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23951/ Thanks @SherinMathew (edit: Oh I see your answer, I'll take a look, thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/y37j8g62/

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          First accordion
        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <p> This is for the first.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Second accordion
        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <p> This is for the second.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this.

```
 data-parent="#accordion"
```

is making it work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Sherin. When I click the upper image, it will collapse, as expected. However, when I click the second image, the previous one didn't close but it collapsed another one for the second image. The first one should close.

Comment: do you mean you want only one item opened at any single point of time?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean..Let me check

Comment: Yes Sherwin, should only be one item. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Sherin, the `data-parent="#accordion"` has been there. I see you put the `panel panel-default` and that did the trick. Now I want to ask what if the accordion groups should all be in one div? My fiddle has them all in a `<div class="accordion-group">`. The class `panel panel-default` won't be useful anymore..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#searchDropdownsPanel">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            Search filters
            <span id="glyphiconicons" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right">
            </span>
        </h3>
    </div><!--panel heading end -->
    <div id="searchDropdownsPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <form {{action "search" on="submit"}}>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    {{yield}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer text-right">
              <button id="searchFilterClearButton" {{action 'clear'}} type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
              <button id="searchFilterSubmitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I use, without the ability to try your code is difficult to help.
The difference between my code and yours is that I use the data-target="#searchDropdownsPanel" to indicate which div has to be collapsed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @manuel I have tried your code in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ but it only has one "panel" to collapse. I tried copying the `div` twice but it doesn't close the previously collapsed panel. This is mine in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ When I click the First Accordion, it will collapse, which is okay. When I click the Second Accordion, the previous one didn't close but it collapsed another one.